# Excel - Manage database to import to CRM

Tags: microsoft-excel, database, import

I have a database where each row contains a variety of company info (name, address, website, phone, etc.  Each row also contains three contacts and their corresponding title.  The headers are CEO Name, CEO Title, Name 2, Title 2, Name 3, Title 3.  My problem is when importing into my CRM, it is only capturing one contact per row.  It appears I need to duplicate the original row (maintaining all of the company info) and to have one contact name on each row.  Please help me make that happen!  Thank you soooooo very much!!!

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please note that [SU] is not a script writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (including any scripts you are using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Impossible to give detailed instructions without seeing the layout of your file but this is the kind of thing you're trying to do:  https://www.google.com/search?q=convert+cross+table+to+list+excel&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b Hopefully one or two of these links will help.

Comment: Thanks so much for the quick response.  The macro below worked well except it only did it for one record and not the entire sheet.  Is there another part of the code I need to include to make it effect the entire sheet?

Comment: Hi Karen - I revised my answer to include how to call a Macro that to loop multiple times. I did a Google search on how to repeat an Excel macro.

Answer (score 2):

You can do what you want based on an Excel Macro. You have to [turn on the Developer tab](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/questions/developer_tab2013.php) in Excel 2013. Then Record a Macro with "Use Relative Reference" turned on and create a loop that will take company, name2, title2 to a new row. Then do it again for name3 and title3.

The macro steps are:

1. go to A2 assuming you have a row header
2. start recording the macro
3. insert a row while you have row 3 highlighted
4. copy and paste company from above on the new row
5. cut and paste name2, title 2 on to the new row
6. insert new row again
7. cute and paste name 3, and title on to the new row
8. then move your cell to a5.
9. This will be your end point to repeat the macro.

[image: Excel Macro]

Your recorded Macro should look something like this:

```
Sub Macro2()
'
' Macro2 Macro
'

'
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Rows("1:1").EntireRow.Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Range("A1").Select
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 3).Range("A1").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Cut
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, -2).Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 3).Range("A1").Select
    Selection.Cut
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, -2).Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Rows("1:1").EntireRow.Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Range("A1").Select
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    ActiveCell.Offset(-2, 5).Range("A1").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Cut
    ActiveCell.Offset(2, -4).Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    ActiveCell.Offset(-2, 5).Range("A1").Select
    Selection.Cut
    ActiveCell.Offset(2, -4).Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, -2).Range("A1").Select
End Sub
```

If you need to repeat more than once, then you have [another Macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18279641/running-a-macro-multiple-times) that calls this Macro the number of times you want:

```
Sub Test()
Call Macro2(3) 'run macro 3 times
End Sub
```